# run flask on apache on windows

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

Here's the issue.
I am trying to deploy my flask app in apache2.4 Server using mod_wsgi.After configuration,my apache server start to run on my computer.But when I visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/ **the page doesn't display as my wish**.

Here's my **flask code**.

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

And here's my **virtual host config**.

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
        ServerAdmin example@company.com   
        DocumentRoot C:\flask       
        WSGIScriptAlias / C:\flask\test.wsgi
        <Directory "C:\flask">
        Require all granted
        Require host ip
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**My wsgi code.**

```
import sys  

#Expand Python classes path with your app's path  
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/flask")  

from test import app as application

#Put logging code (and imports) here ...  

#Initialize WSGI app object  
application = app
```

**The page is like this:**
[**It says 'Internal Server Error'.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB68C.jpg)

Thank everyone!

Comment: And what does the Apache error logs say? If nothing, add ``app.debug = True`` to the WSGI script file to see if that will cause Flask to display details of error if Flask generated it.

Comment: How did you install mod_wsgi on a non-UNIX platform?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton After asking this question,I turned to the apache error logs and found it said "name 'app' is not defined",so I delete the 'as application' in the wsgi code,and it works!

Comment: @mmenschig There's a passage about how to deploy flaks app on windows with apache and mod_wsgi.I found a zip file that included mod_wsgi binary file(*.so) on the Internet.I just follow the tutorial and successfully loaded it on apache server.

Comment: The preferred method of installing mod_wsgi on Windows is to do a ``pip install mod_wsgi`` and then run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to get the configuration you need to put in Apache configuration file.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yeah,I saw this method on the github tutorial,but it doesn't tell me what parameter should I give while running mod_wsgi-express which cause me to give up.Maybe I should try it in some time.

Comment: You can't use ``mod_wsgi-express start-server`` on Windows to start Apache. You only run the command ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to get the configuration to put in your existing Apache setup. You then use normal host mechanism to start/stop Apache and not ``mod_wsgi-express``.

Comment: umm,so the command `mod_wsgi-express module-config` is just a configuration command?And after that I should start up the apache service as usual?Well,the passage I read tell me to use command `mod_wsgi-express start-server`,no wonder it doesn't work.Thx,forgive my awful english.

Answer (score 0):

remove the code

`#Initialize WSGI app object

application = app`

maybe it works

Comment: 忘了最后是怎么解决的了，似乎是虚拟主机的问题。I forgot how it was solved at last, seems like the virtual host was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

first remove last line from test.wsgi file.

(i.e application = app)

then check http://127.0.0.1:5000/, if it works then good,

if not then, add the following lines at the bottom of httpd.conf file.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / C:\flask\test.wsgi
<Directory C:\flask>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then check again http://127.0.0.1:5000/. it will work definitely.